# Why the paramters are adjusted in ojalgo?

Tags: optimization, ojalgo

Can someone explain me the function of the parameter "adjusted", which calls e.g. getAdjustmentExponent(), for lower, upper, weights,... in the class ModelEntity of the ojalgo package? I can understand the function if it should improve the numerical performance but I cannot understand why the constraints are adjusted like this:

Problem to compute:

```
min  2x+y  
s.t. x+y=3,
     0<=x<=3.0,
     0<=y<=0.05 <--
```

into ojalgo problem

```
min  2x+y 
s.t. x+y=3
     0<=x<=3.0
     0<=y<=0.5 <--
```

Is this a bug or do I overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done to improve the numerical performance. Is there a problem with how  it works, do you get incorrect solutions?

Your example suggests that something is wrong, but is that really what happens?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The general implementation should be correct so far I could test it. 

My problem is ill-conditioned and thus I got wrong results. Finally, I found solver settings which work (with deactivated compensate function). I reactivated it and I have an issue (https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo-extensions/issues/3). This is probably only a cplex extension specific problem.

Comment: Fixed that problem. You can turn off ojAlgo's presolvers by calling ```ExpressionsBasedModel.clearPresolvers();```

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working well. Good to know that I can deactivate the presolver. However, I like to have such a tool.
Is it correct that expressions are not adjusted at the moment? I know it is probably not always a good idea but sometimes it can be nice to transform "0.01a+0.03b<=0.04" into "1.0a+3.0b<=4".

Comment: The parameter adjustment is not a presolver, and cannot be disabled.  (It disables itself if the input parameters are too extreme.)

Comment: I realized it. Furthermore, my last question is obsolete as expression parameter adjustments are executed.